# Core Data NSPredicate with a fetch property as criteria?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have 2 entities Card and CardStatus, stored in different persistent stores. Card also contains a fetched property "userData", which is used to retrieve from CardStatus the status corresponding to a Card entity. This works fine.

I'd like to execute a fetch request on Card whilst using my fetched property as criteria in the predicate. Is it technically possible?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Card"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:delegate.managedObjectContext];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"userData.externalKey != nil"];            
NSArray *results = [delegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

But I receive the following exception:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath userData.externalKey
>   not found in entity

What's happening?

Comment: What is userData.externalKey? Is this property in card entity?

Comment: userData is a fetched property (in the entity **Card**) and externalKey is a property of the entity **CardStatus**.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but did you already read the part about fetched properties in the Core Data manual? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7

Comment: Yes, I did. The fetched property works fine. Any idea?

Comment: @Micky1407: I strongly assume that this is not possible. A fetch request is translated to a SQLite query for the underlying store. Your request would require quering *two* Sqlite stores.

Comment: Good point, it makes sense (and would explain the problems I'm facing). How would you do that then? Any other way to extract my Card entities based on the status without doing a first fetch then a filter? (I tested this, it's working, but the performance is a bit.....)